# Print a triangular pattern of asterisks

Tags: for-loop, python-3.x

I am required to use nested for loops and `print('*', end=' ')` to create the pattern shown [here](http://prntscr.com/4vzp9m):
[image]

And here is my code. I have figured out the first two.

```
n = 0

print ("Pattern A")
for x in range (0,11):
    n = n + 1
    for a in range (0, n-1):
        print ('*', end = '')
    print()
print ('')
print ("Pattern B")
for b in range (0,11):
    n = n - 1
    for d in range (0, n+1):
        print ('*', end = '')
    print()
print ('')
```

When i start pattern C and D, i try the following:

```
print ("Pattern C")
for e in range (11,0,-1):
    n = n + 1
    for f in range (0, n+1):
        print ('*', end = '')
    print()
print ('')
print ("Pattern D")
for g in range (11,0,-1):
    n = n - 1
    for h in range (0, n-1):
        print ('*', end = '')
    print()
```

But the result is the same as A and B. Help is appreciated!

Comment: Seems we can start a library of code to print all those shapes of asterisks used as beginner's exercise: [Pyramid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179423/upside-down-pyramid-py), [M](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394149/draw-an-m-shaped-pattern-with-nested-loops), [Triangels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26352412/python-print-a-triangular-pattern-of-asterisks), [Diamond](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364162/print-shape-in-python), [Hollow square](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108446/drawing-a-hollow-asterisk-square)

Comment: Indeed we can @cfi +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both patterns C and D require leading spaces and you are not printing any spaces, just stars.

Here is alternative code that prints the required leading spaces:

```
print ("Pattern C")
for e in range (11,0,-1):
    print((11-e) * ' ' + e * '*')

print ('')
print ("Pattern D")
for g in range (11,0,-1):
    print(g * ' ' + (11-g) * '*')
```

Here is the output:

```
Pattern C
***********
 **********
  *********
   ********
    *******
     ******
      *****
       ****
        ***
         **
          *

Pattern D

          *
         **
        ***
       ****
      *****
     ******
    *******
   ********
  *********
 **********
```

In more detail, consider this line:

```
print((11-e) * ' ' + e * '*')
```

It prints `(11-e)` spaces followed by `e` stars.  This provides the leading spaces needed to make the patterns.

If your teacher wants nested loops, then you may need to convert `print((11-e) * ' ' + e * '*')` into loops printing each space, one at a time, followed by each star, one at a time.

#### Pattern C via nested loops

If you followed the hints I gave about nested loops, you would have arrived at a solution for Pattern C like the following:

```
print ("Pattern C")
for e in range (11,0,-1):
    #print((11-e) * ' ' + e * '*')
    for d in range (11-e):
        print (' ', end = '')
    for d in range (e):
        print ('*', end = '')
    print()
```

Comment: YEs it works. Here is another part i forgot to add, that the teacher said we should use: print('*', end=' ')

Comment: Yes.  Actually, you will need two loops.  For the C pattern, the loop first prints `(11-e)` spaces, presumable with `print(' ', end='')`.  The second prints `e` stars with `print('*', end='')`.

Comment: so the print ('*', end = '') is technically already on there so i dont have to write it?

Comment: i believe it works for now. i'll tell you if it doesn't work later. thanks a lot! @john1024

Comment: sorry, we can't use multiplying a string. can't do (11-e) * ' ' + e * '*'

Comment: @Player72 I updated the answer with the complete cheat for Pattern C.

Comment: i am having difficulty with pattern d. @John1024

Comment: What kind of difficulty?  What have you come up with so far?

Comment: Sorry about that, I figured it out. Question closed thank you. @John1024

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in range(1,n+1): print '{:>{}}'.format('#'*i, n)
this is For pattern D


for i in range(1,n-1): print '{:>{}}'.format('#'*i, n)
this is For pattern c
```

Answer (score 2):

Pythonic way of doing this. Just 1 line of code (using list comprehension) for each pattern.

```
n = 10

# for A
print('\n'.join(['*'*i for i in range(1,n+1)]))

#output
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********


# for B
print('\n'.join(['*'*i for i in range(n+1,0,-1)]))

#output
***********
**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*

# for C
print('\n'.join([' '*(n-i) + '*'*i for i in range(n,0,-1)]))

#output
**********
 *********
  ********
   *******
    ******
     *****
      ****
       ***
        **
         *


# for D
print('\n'.join([' '*(n-i) + '*'*i for i in range(1,n+1)]))

#output
         *
        **
       ***
      ****
     *****
    ******
   *******
  ********
 *********
**********
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print("Pattern C")
n=int(input("Enter number of rows: ")) 
for i in range (n,0,-1):
    print((n-i) * ' ' + i * '*')
```

Answer (score 1):

learn an easy way:
**code1:**

```
for n in range(0,5):
    n +=1
    print ("*" *(0+n))
```

**what it does:**

1. for n in range(0,5): --> call a range of no of times you want loop to execute
2. increment value of int n by one, so starting from range 0 to 5 every time for loop runs it increments int n by 1
3. now print string "*" and multiply it by value of int n+0, So when int n=0 as per logic int n increments by 1 and print ("*" *(0+n)) = print ("*" *(0+1)) = *

**output:**
*
**
***
****
*****

**code2:**

```
for n in range(-5,0):
    n +=1
    print ("*" *(0-n+1))
```

**output:**
****
***
**
*

Answer (score 1):

```
i=0
while(i<5):
    j=0
    while(j<=i):
        print("*",end="") #end="" is given to stay on same line
        j=j+1
    print("")  #it will take u to new line
    i=i+1
    j=0
i=i-2
j=i
while(i>=0):
    while(j>=0):
        print("*",end="")
        j=j-1
    print() #will also work
    i=i-1
    j=i
```

> this will also work

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range (1,n):    # loop will execute from 1 to 4(n-1)
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print("*",end="")
    print()
for i in range (n+1,1,-1):
    for j in range(i,1,-1):
        print("*",end="")
    print()
```

## using for loop

Answer (score 1):

```
def fun (n):
    return n
n=int(raw_input("Enter the number"))
print "The given number is",n
for i in range (n,0,-1):
    print "*"*i
```

output:

```
The given number is 3
***
**
*
```

Comment: This only covers case B.

Answer (score 1):

using spaces you can create different- different patterns:
1.

```
def pattern(limit):

    for i in range(limit+1):
        print((limit-i)*"  "+ ' #'*i)    

pattern(4)

Output: 
       #
     # #
   # # #
 # # # #
```

2.remove one space from above code and pattern will be changed in a pyramid

```
def pattern(limit):
    for i in range(limit+1):
        print((limit-i)*" "+ ' #'*i)       
pattern(4)

output: #
       # #
      # # #
     # # # #
```

3: no space  print((limit-i)*""+ ' #'*i)  will create

```
 #
 # #
 # # #
 # # # #
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(0,5):
for j in range(0,i+1):
    print("*",end="")
print()
for k in range(5,0,-1):
for l in range(k-1,0,-1):
    print("*",end="")
print()
```

## *
** 
***
****
*****
****
*** 
** 
*

Answer (score 1):

The function:

```
def arrow(my_char, max_length):
    for i in range(max_length*2):
        if i <= max_length:
            print(my_char*i)
        if i > max_length:
            print(my_char*(max_length*2-i))
```

The main():

```
def main():
    print(arrow('*', 8))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Answer (score 1):

**Pattern 1**

```
for x in range(1,11):
    print("*"*x)
```

**Output**

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********
```

**Pattern 2**

```
for x in range(10,0,-1):
    print("*"*x)
```

**Output**

```
**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

**Pattern 3**

```
 i=0
    for x in range(10,0,-1):
            print(" "*i,end="")


       print("*"*x)
        i+=1
```

**Output**

```
**********
 *********
  ********
   *******
    ******
     *****
      ****
       ***
        **
         *
```

**Pattern 4**

```
i=10
for x in range(1,11):
        print(" "*i,end="")
        print("*"*x)
        i-=1
```

**Output**

```
          *
         **
        ***
       ****
      *****
     ******
    *******
   ********
  *********
 **********
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one!

```
  a)
            *                                                                                                                                                    
            **                                                                                                                                                   
            ***                                                                                                                                                  
            ****                                                                                                                                                 
            *****  

            public class Main { 
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    int n=5;
                    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
                    {
                        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
                        {
                           System.out.print("*"); 
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
             }

            b)
            *****                                                                                                                                                
             ****                                                                                                                                                
              ***                                                                                                                                                
               **                                                                                                                                                
                *


            public class Main {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                int n=5;
                for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
                {
                        for(int j=1;j<=(i-1);j++)
                        {
                           System.out.print(" "); 
                        }
                        for(int j=i;j<=n;j++)
                        {
                            System.out.print("*");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                }
            }
         }

        c)
            *                                                                                                                                                
           **                                                                                                                                                
          ***                                                                                                                                                
         ****                                                                                                                                                
        *****

        public class Main
        {
            public static void main(String[] args)
            {       int n=5;
                    for(int i=n;i>0;i--)        
                    {
                       for(int j=1;j<=(i-1);j++)
                       {
                          System.out.print(" "); 
                       }
                       for(int j=i;j<=n;j++)
                       {
                          System.out.print("*");
                       }
                       System.out.println();
                }
            }
         }

        d)
        *****                                                                                                                                                
        ****                                                                                                                                                 
        ***                                                                                                                                                  
        **                                                                                                                                                   
        * 


        public class Main
        {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                int n=5;
                for(int i=n;i>0;i--)
                {
                    for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
                    {
                        System.out.print("*");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var n = 5;

    for(int row = 0 ; row < n; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 1; col <= n; col++)
        {
            if(col < n - row)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine();

    }
```

**(D)**

Comment: Hi kuldeep chopra. Please consider adding more information.

Answer (score 0):

for i in range(1,7):
    print(" "*(7-i)+"*"*(i))

**Output :**

```
  *
 **
***
```

---

---

---