# Nested Loops to generate triangles, wrong way

Tags: python-3.x, nested-loops, triangular

I need to use nested loops to generate a triangle. The output needs to look like this.

```
How many lines? 7
0000000
 000000
  00000
   0000
    000
     00
      0
```

Currently I have attempted to use this, but I am unsure on how to get the 0's to face the right way.

```
def main():
start = int(input("How many lines?"))
end = 0
increment = -1

for rows in range(start,end,increment):
    for colums in range(rows):
        print("0", end= "")
    print() 
main()
```

And the output of this is.

```
How many lines?7
0000000
000000
00000
0000
000
00
0
```

I am just unsure how to fix it, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Print a triangular pattern of asterisks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26352412/python-print-a-triangular-pattern-of-asterisks)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input("how many lines?"))
for e in range (a,0,-1):
    print((11-e) * ' ' + e * '0')
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include some commentary on your code - how it works, what the caveats are, etc.