# Inversed pyramids patterns in Python -two patterns same figure

Tags: python

Trying to build pyramids in Python, something similar to the following

```
****
***
**
*     *
     **
    ***
   ****
```

Please note there are TWO stars on line 4.  Currently all I have is this:

```
for stars in range(4,0,-1):
    print("*"*stars)
```

Which yields the following:

```
****
***
**
*
```

Please advise.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question)[https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @user3717717, your question regarding if it written as a Var or in a text file, in those contexts, probably written as a variable `stars` since the characters are an explicit string `"*"`

Comment: Thoughts! You should write two functions: `stars_on_left` and `stars_on_right`. They should take a line number and a total number of star rows, and return how many stars should be on each side of the row. For instance `stars_on_left(row=0, total_rows=4)` should give 4. `stars_on_right(row=4, total_rows=4)` should give 1. You should be able to use that and the knowledge that each row should be 7 characters wide to do what you need to do.

Comment: my solution https://repl.it/I74q/0

Answer (score 0):

Super ugly, adopted from this answer [Python: Print a triangular pattern of asterisks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26352507/1248974).

```
for stars in range(4,1,-1):
    print("*" * stars)

print("*     *")

for g in range (5,2,-1):
    print(g * ' ' + (7-g) * '*')
```

Disclaimer: I don't yet know the technicalities why it works, but I would happily dissect it and explain why it does if needed! :)

Comment: Works wonders thanks.  Is there any way to remove the string "*      *"  so that the solution does not rely on strings?  Anyhow fantastic solution.

Comment: Glad to help, I'm sure there is, I agree with you, I thought that was a weak-hack workaround, I'll work with it a bit more and update if I can get that part out of the solution.

Comment: https://repl.it/I74q/0

Comment: How is this a duplicate, the two figures intersect?

Comment: The moderators probably didn't want the question to be answered, so they used that link I included as a reason to close the question ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ . Anyhow, I think yhoyo's answer is more what you were looking for.   @yhoyo

Comment: actually if you run yhoyo's code with `piramid (4, 0, -1)`, you should get the correct output.

Comment: Just spent an hour making a new creative solution to the problem and the mods lock it, fantastic. Leaving the question open can generate new ideas to look at the same problem which someone else may find useful.

Comment: @rosh, agreed, I expected they'd do that, that's why I threw up this hideous answer before they locked it, feel free to link to a repl.it of your code like yhoyo did if you want to share it if someone may find it useful. Or you could post your own Question and Answer it with your code. (quickly before it also may get locked!)