# Triangular n x n pattern program

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, for-loop

This program is supposed to print an n x n triangular pattern like this:

n = 6

```
* * * * * *
. * * * * *
. . * * * *
. . . * * *
. . . . * *
. . . . . *
```

However I am getting this:

n = 6

```
* * * * * *
. . . . . .
. . . . . .
. . . . . .
. . . . . .
. . . . . .
```

where is my mistake?

```
import sys

n = int(sys.argv[1])

def triangle(n):
    for i in range(n):
        if i == 0:
            for k in range(n):
                print('*', end=' ')
            print()
        if i > 0:
            for k in range(n):
                print('.', end=' ')
            print()

triangle(n)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should use *duck debugging*: explain your rubber duck how your program works.

Comment: Perhaps this would help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26352412/python-print-a-triangular-pattern-of-asterisks

Comment: @CristianOlaru it didn't really help me :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are printing stars only if you are on the first line and dots for every other line. You need to print dots and stars on each line increasing the number of dots and decreasing the stars:

```
def triangle(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for k in range(i):
            print('.', end=' ')

        for k in range(n - i):
            print('*', end=' ')

        print()
```

Comment: This is exactly the same code that my (earlier) answer has.

Comment: It had a different counters in the `for` loop initially that you consequently edited and I also wanted to try and give a better explanation because you didn't have that either.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking the loop index simply use it to print the number of dots. Then print `n - i` stars, e.g.:

```
def triangle(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for k in range(i):
            print('.', end=' ')    
        for k in range(n-i):
            print('*', end=' ')
        print()
```

Or just using the multiplication operator:

```
def triangle(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print(*["."]*i + ["*"]*(n-i), sep=" ")
```

Comment: I did this and it worked, however I have a question. Why is the first for loop skipped the first time and the second one runs?

Comment: The first time it's `range(0)`, which is an empty iterator (i.e. `list(range(0)) == []`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Its alot more simple

```
count = 0
count2 = 5
while count2 >= 1:
    for i in range(count):
        print(".", end = " ")
    for i in range(count2):
        print("*", end = " ")
    print()
    count = count + 1
    count2 = count2 - 1
```